# Can't Use Data from Selection in HTML with PHP To Validate RegEx Pattern

Tags: php, html, regex

```
<?php   

$selectedOption = $_POST['patOption'];
$text = "";
$replaceText = "";
$replacedText = "";
$containString = "/\b($text)\b/";
$containEmail = "/\b([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{2,})+@([A-Za-z0-9._]{2,})+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b/";
$containPhone = "/^(\+(998))+\-([0-9]{2})+\-([0-9]{3})+\-([0-9]{4})/";

$match = "Not checked yet.";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $pattern = $_POST["pattern"];
    $text = $_POST["text"];
    $replaceText = $_POST["replaceText"];

    $replacedText = preg_replace($pattern, $replaceText, $text);

    if (preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
        $match = "Match!";
    } else {
        $match = "Does not match!";
    }
}

?>
```

html

```
<body>
    <h1>Validation Tests</h1>
    <h3>Choose Pattern:</h3>
    <select name="patOption">
        <option>OPTIONS...</option>
        <option value="<?= $containString ?>">Contain_String</option>
        <option value="<?= $containEmail ?>">Contain_Email</option>
        <option value="<?= $containPhone ?>">Contain_Phone</option>
    </select>

    <form action="regex_valid_form.php" method="post">
        <dl>
            <dt>Pattern</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="pattern" value="<?= $selectedOption ?>"></dd>

            <dt>Text (Ex.)</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="text" value="<?= $text ?>"></dd>

            <dt>Replace Text</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="replaceText" value="<?= $replaceText ?>"></dd>

            <dt>Output Text</dt>
            <dd><?= $match ?></dd>

            <dt>Replaced Text</dt>
            <dd> <code><?= $replacedText ?></code></dd>

            <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd><input type="submit" value="Check"></dd>
        </dl>
    </form>


</body>
```

I Wanna Use Choosen Value From Options To Validate RegEx Pattern in PHP:

- It should get RegEx from Var in PHP and insert into 'Pattern' field when I 
  choose corresponding option and validate with given 'value' in 'Text' field 
  and Output whether it Matched or Not

Validation Page:

[image]

Comment: Your select is outside of the form, result: the patOption isn't send when you submit the form.

Comment: If you want to update the pattern field without submitting the form, you have to use Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the help